# How to resolve " cannot resolve com.intuit.karate:karate-gatling:1.2.0"?

Tags: intellij-idea, performance-testing, karate

I already have an e2e in karate for my api tests and  i am trying use gatling for the performance testing.
i have installed scala(i am using intellij ide)
i have java jdk 15 and my environment variables are correctly set for java and gatling
i have added framework support for scala class
i have added below dependencies to my pom
i am still getting " cannot resolve com.intuit.karate:karate-gatling:1.2.0"?

```
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.3</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
        <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>

 <dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
      <artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
      <version>${karate.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
      <artifactId>karate-junit4</artifactId>
      <version>${karate.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

No that's not how you do it. Take some time to read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling

Or first get the demo example working and then customize it for your needs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/examples/gatling

And 1.1.0 is the latest, not 1.2.0

Comment: Just a question ,does gatling works well with jdk 15 ?

Comment: @UmmulkhairKadri yes it does